# Why would a command that executes in R fail in R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using the latest versions of R and R Studio on a 64 bit Windows 7 system and have successfully constructed the R program needed to complete my course project.  However, I am required to turn in R markdown output as compiled html.  My program runs to about 70% completion in R markdown and then throws an error that I cannot understand.  I can't complete my project due to this R markdown problem.

Here's more detail:

My markdown document begins with:

````
---
title: 'Final Report: Prediction Assignment'
author: "Donald Chambless"
date: "June 23, 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
..................................
..................................
````

and all of the code that follows executes correctly in R markdown until this statement:

```
trainingPred <- predict(RandomTreeModel, trainingData[ , -54])
```

This line fails in R markdown with the following error message:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'accel_forearm_y' not found       calls:  ... predict.train -> model.frame -> model.frame.default ->   eval -> eval

I don't understand what's going on. Can anyone help?

I'm a newcomer to Stack Overflow, but I hope I have explained my problem sufficiently.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You will need to provide a bit more to go on.  I.e. some data, and the shortest amount of code that replicates your error.  Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to learn handy tips on how to construct a great question.

Comment: It seems that `accel_forearm_y` is not defined. Make sure that the lines that defined it in your original script are also present in your markdown file. If you are using RStudio, you can press Ctrl+Alt+R to run the Code in all your chunks. This might make it easier to debug. If you cleaned your Envrionment before doing this, you can easily check whether the variable `accel_forearm_y` has been created.

Comment: Hi Don, first make sure all your r object names are correct. Second, try storing your test data into another variable like:
`testData <- traindata[,-54`] 
`trainingPred <- predict(RandomTreeModel, testData)`

Before running R markdown, check if it works in R console.

Comment: I can't find the green arrows I see referenced, so I'll have to just say "thanks."